# How to resolve WPF Visual Studio 2008 message "this member is defined more than once"

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, syntax-error

In a code behind file in a WPF project the variables representing controls defined in XAML (e.g. closeButton) display red squiggly lines underneath with a tooltip message indicating "this member is defined more than once".

When I 'find all references' on these control variables I see there are 2 references, one in a .g.cs file and another in a g.i.cs file. Hence VS thinks items are defined twice.

A rebuild solves problem for a bit, but then the red squiggly lines return!

I don't think I've seen references to a .g.i.cs file before, but I've read they are generated in memory to help with intellisense.

I'm not sure what I may have accidentally done to provoke this issue but any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can we see a little of the code, please?